# smtp sending mail as "Charlie &"

Tags: freebsd, jail, ssmtp

I'm trying to use ssmtp to send mail from my jails to the mail hub in one of them.

However, the `from name` isn't properly being renamed. The `&` isn't being replaced with root so I'm getting mails from `Charlie &`instead of `Charlie Root`.

This is my config:

```
root=mail@xxx.yy

mailhub=10.0.0.3

rewriteDomain=JAILNAME.xxx.yy

#hostname=_HOSTNAME_

FromLineOverride=YES

UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

Something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

`Charlie &` is the Full Name of the root user.

Use the command:

```
chpass
```

to change the root user information, in your case, the full name.